# Need some help with design for reduced friction acceleration of a ferromagnetic mass through a barrel

Tags: electromagnetism, switching, coil, electric-machine, actuator

I would like to levitate (by that I mean just enough to not make contact with the surface of the barrel) and accelerate a ferromagnetic mass along a barrel of a certain length. I have a few questions about design and how to accomplish this. For context, I have a Mechanical Engineering back ground and I'm trying to teach myself EE topics. So here goes:

This is a rough idea of what I'm planning on doing:

[image]

I'm planning on switching power to the outer windings around the barrel as the mass travels along the barrel and use capacitors to power them with high currents. I still have to figure out the switching circuits and safety and a different power supply for the windings in the barrel. I'm assuming they don't need high current to keep the mass from falling down.

1. Are there any glaring errors with my design idea? Will EM fields orthogonal to each other- from the windings around the barrel and the ones in the barrel interfere and cause issues for each other?
2. Is there a simulation software that will help me play around with solenoids and currents and see what the resulting EM fields look like? Both Ansys and Solidworks seem to have a way to simulate electromagnetics, but I'm just trying to see what the EM fields look like from a bunch of solenoids- maybe they are overkill for what I'm trying to do?
3. If this is stupid, what can I do to better understand EM fields to design something like this? I'm thinking about going back and looking through some books on Electric Machines. Will that be enough or will I have to look into EM field theory to be able to design stuff like this?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Frictionless? Not possible unless you remove the air.

Comment: Alright, let's call it reduced friction

Comment: This is a pretty complicated thing to do with no electrical experience.

Comment: look up Prof Eric Laithwaite's 'Magnetic River', levitates and acclerates with one electrical machine, but it's not a barrel design

Comment: If the mass is ferromagnetic, then think, is it attracted to or repelled by the levitating magnets at the bottom? Hint, a non-magnetic metal like aluminium will be repelled by the eddy currents. A magnet will be repelled by a suitably oriented field. But a ferromagnetic mass?

Comment: What is the purpose of this, what's the application?

Answer (score 1):

The way you have drawn it, seems to not make sense to me on first glance. If you just coil wire around the barrel, you will create an axial magnetic field inside, which is slightly stronger towards the walls. That means the mass would get attracted to the walls.

Moreover, there is some theorem (whose name I forgot) that states that magnetic levitation is impossible for a mass with positive magnetic susceptibility (e.g. ferromagnetic) in a passive/stationary magnetic environment (e.g. permanent magnets).

That situation will be at best metastable and requires active control to achieve long confinement, e.g. for things like magnetic bearings. In this case you would also have many radially pointing electromagnets and control them at a very fast rate.

If you want passive confinement, the mass must be (strongly) diamagnetic, such as a superconductor. The closest you can come to this from a practical point of view is something with very high conductivity, e.g. aluminium or copper. This will be repelled at least for a short instant when you switch the field on/off, due to the eddy currents. But again, I doubt that the solenoid wire arrangement is helpful to achieve this.